# Why did she choose O6G?

Tags: knowledge, visual, cipher, chess, letters

## He gave her 8 choices. 7 lead to death, one lets her continue.

- O6A
- O6B
- I6C
- U6D
- I6E
- I6F
- O6G
- O6H

### Of course, he knew she had no idea. He turned the hour glass and gave her 5 items from his suitcase.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### She still had no idea when the hour glass was over. With his giant smile: don't worry, you have another hour to find out.

### He turned the hour glass once more and told her:

> You are missing three letters, they are within:

[image]

[image]

## #

## Why did she choose O6G?

## Hints

This hint was added following @user118161's answer

> For second part, what he gave her was three papers. One printed all black, another empty one, white color and one with a # printed in huge font size.

### Hint 1 - 8th of April

> The five items share something in common. What they share has 5 letters.

### Hint 2 - 15th of April

> The three rightly chosen letters from **black** **white** and **hashtag** plus the letters of words in Hints 1, when correctly concatenated, form a person's surname that help identify why she choose O6G :)

### Hint 3 - 15th of May

> They are playing Chess
>  I modified a little Hint 2 making it better. That is, his surname is 8 letters length.

Comment: Does the ship and the card have anything to do with the movies Titanic and Joker?

Comment: @user118161, well... looks like you only have 3 items left :)

Comment: Apparently there's a movie called Green Book, and  a movie called The Yellow Dress, but what is the statue thing? Is it a gladiator or something?

Comment: @user118161 What about searching gladiator on your favorite search engine? I have edited the Yellow Dress so you are better well directed :)

Comment: Yup, gladiator is a movie. Can't figure out the yellow dress with a floral pattern, though. Movie is a 5 letter word. Titanic(1997), Joker(2019), Green Book(2018), Gladiator(2000),

Comment: I reverseimagesearched the yellow dress, and apparently it's from La La land(2016)

Comment: Hmmm... there aren't that many 3 letter names. Bea at first glance is seen.

Comment: maybe its time for another hint hehe

Comment: @oAlt! Yes, adding it

Comment: @JKHA please check the tag description of [[tag:cryptography]] and ensure that you mean to use that tag, as opposed to [[tag:cipher]]. You would use [cipher] if your puzzle involves encoding/decoding a message, the algorithm of an encryption, etc. You would use [cryptography] if your puzzle involves *strategies for how to use encryption* - the idea of public-key cryptography, rather than the algorithm for how the public key alters the text.

Comment: I think this sadly may never be solved, @JKHA.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer, based on @user118161's comments:

The pictures represent:

> Oscar winning movies: Lala Land, Joker, Titanic, Green Book, and Gladiator

So, the solution to Hint 1 is:

> Oscar, which has 5 letters

Comment: As does 'movie'.

Comment: As does 'films', and for that matter, 'thing'. But, would the op choose 5 academy award winners if a more generic answer was wanted?

Comment: I think it is likely that 'Oscar' plays a role in the solution to the puzzle, but the purpose of Hint 1 was just to get us to figure out why those images were chosen in the first place. I suspect that 'movie' is what the OP had in mind with that hint. We'll know soon enough.

Comment: First letter of oscar is o, which is also first letter of o6g.